# How to get motion working with ftp server?

Tags: linux, ftp, motion

have tried changing the config file to this:

```
target_dir ftp://user:pass@mysite.com:21/public_html/dir
```

but motion returns errors.  want to be able to put mysite.com/dir/stream.flv into a browser and get the stream that would normally show up on my hardrive.

I have also tried the wput on_photo_save, but it tells me that I have to many connections from my machines, and I don't want to have to have a frame rate of 2 per minute.

Motion is motion detecting software, installable in the usual `sudo apt-get install` way.

Comment: drnessie/ tom Your new edit isn't more information, it's a new question altogether. Please ask a separate question for that.

Comment: That is what I meant the original question to be though - but I wrote it on a mobile and couldn't read through it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
target_dir /home/user/public_html/dir
```

Comment: If I remember correctly it was a remote host - but I'll give you this anyway as you're the closest to an answer